# Draggable UITextField enters editing when it shouldn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, draggable

I'm developing an iOS6 app for iPad. I have coded a subclass of UITextField that enables the user to drag, pinch and rotate the field around the view. The problem is that if you pinch the field with no rotation, after finishing the gesture, it enters in editing mode. This should not happen, and I've added some lines that disable that, but it doesn't stop. Here I my code:

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{
if (gesturing==YES) {
       return NO;
}else  return YES;
}


 - (void) tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) pinchRecognizer {

if (gesturing==NO) {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
}


- (void) pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) pinchRecognizer {

CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:self.font.pointSize*(scale)];


//self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, scale, scale);

[self sizeToFit];


pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;

if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    gesturing =YES;   

}

if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    gesturing =YES;

}

if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    gesturing =NO;

}


 }


- (void) panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {

CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.superview];
CGPoint imageViewPosition = self.center;
imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;

self.center = imageViewPosition;
[panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView: self.superview];



if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    gesturing=YES;       

}

if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    gesturing=NO;



}


  }


 - (void) rotationDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotationRecognizer{  


CGFloat angle = rotationRecognizer.rotation;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, angle);
rotationRecognizer.rotation = 0.0;

if (rotationRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    gesturing = YES;
}

if (rotationRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    gesturing = NO;
}

 }


- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bydefault value of `gesturing` is `NO`, if you don't initialize it to `YES`. Have debugged and figured out which gesture recognizer is detected first whenever you try to apply `pinch`?
You support simultaneous gesture recognition and hence when you put to apply `pinch`, your finger's touch may get detected as `pan`. If it is the case then `if(gesturing == NO)` condition in `tapDetected:` method gets satisfied and your textField becomes first responder.